# Convergence of $\sin (n_k x)$

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

If I have a set $E$ which is a set of points $x\in(-\pi,\pi)$ such that for an increasing sequence $\{ n_k \}$ a sequence of functions $\sin(n_k\,x)$ converges, where do I start proving that measure of $E$ is zero?

Comment: You really should give some thoughts, context, background ...

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Suppose $\sin (n_kx) $ converges pointwise to some $f$ on a set $E\subset (-\pi,\pi)$ of positive measure. Observe that $\int_Ef^2 = \lim_{k\to \infty}  \int_E f(x)\cdot (\sin n_kx) \, dx = \lim_{k\to \infty} \int_E  (\sin n_kx)^2 \, dx$

Comment: So we can apply a Lebesgue-Riemann lemma? What if we express this as a $\int_E \left( \frac{1}{2} - \frac{\cos(2n_k \, x)}{2} \right) d \mu$, so in a limit we'll get $\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty}\int_E \left(\frac{1}{2} - \frac{\cos(2n_k \, x)}{2}\right)d\mu=m(A)$